# SQL PIVOT two tables

Tags: sql, pivot

I'm trying to sort something out for work where I can get quantity a certain product line from each warehouse. I'm using SAP B1 software

```
SELECT T0.[ItemCode], [01],[BNE],[SHOP],[Transit]
    FROM OITM T0 INNER JOIN OITW T1 ON T0.[ItemCode] = T1.[ItemCode]
    PIVOT(SUM(T1.OnHand) FOR T1.WhsCode IN([01],[BNE],[SHOP],[Transit])) AS PivotTable
    Group By T0.[ItemCode]
```

No matter what I attempt to adjust to problem solve, I keep getting more error codes, like comparable types or bound errors... I suppose it is obvious but can anyone help?

**This what the data comes in like:**  (with a few hundred product lines)

```
Product Code    Warehouse    Quantity
PROD0001          01            50 
                  BNE           94   
                  Shop          80   
                  Transit       80 
-------------------------------------    
PROD0002          01            10  
                  BNE           20   
                  Shop          00   
                  Transit       70
-------------------------------------  
PROD0003          01            99  
                  BNE           62   
                  Shop          20   
                  Transit       15
```

**And I'm wanting to achieve something like this via a SQL query:**

```
Product Code    01   BNE   Shop   Transit  
PROD0001        50   94    80     80 
PROD0002        10   20    00     70
PROD0003        99   62    20     15
```

Comment: Format your code first, pls.

Comment: Could you supply sample data and the expected result? So everybody can help you easily.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a database product

Answer (score 0):

**Create Table:**

```
create table demo
(
   productcode nvarchar(50),
   Warehouse nvarchar(50),
   Quantity int
);
```

**Insert Table:**

```
insert into demo values

('PROD0001','01','50'),
('PROD0001','BNE','94'),
('PROD0001','Shop','80'),
('PROD0001','Transit','80'),
('PROD0002','01','10'),
('PROD0002','BNE','20'),
('PROD0002','Shop','00'),
('PROD0002','Transit','70'),
('PROD0003','01','99'),
('PROD0003','BNE','62'),
('PROD0003','Shop','20'),
('PROD0003','Transit','15');
```

**SQL Query:**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select [productcode], ' + stuff((
    select distinct ',sum(case [WareHouse] when ' + char(39) + [WareHouse] + char(39) + ' then cast([Quantity] as float) end) as [' + [WareHouse] + ']'
    from demo
    for xml path('')
)
, 1, 1, ''
);

select @sql += ' from [demo] group by [productcode];';

exec(@sql);
```